# Simple interface for collecting issues after a list of validations

Tags: python, object-oriented, design-patterns

```
class RadarChecker:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._issues = set()

    @property
    def issues(self) -> Set[str]:
        return self._issues

    @property
    def _checkers(self) -> Iterable[Callable]:
        return (
            self._check_1,
            self._check_2,
            self._check_3,
        )

    def check(self) -> None:
        for checker in self._checkers:
            ok, issue = checker()
            if not ok:
                self._issues.add(issue)
```

The current interface of the `RadarChecker` class consists of two methods: `check` and `issues`. The whole purpose of the check method is that it triggers computation of the issues that are returned by the issues method. So, all users of `RadarChecker` call issues eventually:

```
checker = RadarChecker()
checker.check()
for issue in checker.issues:
    # process issue
```

Is it possible to provide the same functionality with a simpler interface?

I'm thinking about defining the `RadarIssues` class that implements the `Iterable[str]` interface. We provide the same info to `RadarIssues` that we do to `RadarChecker` but instead of calling `issues` to get the issues, the users would simply iterate over the instance of `RadarIssues`. This would look roughly as follows:

```
radar_issues = RadarIssues()
for issue in radar_issues:
    # process issue
```

Is it better? I will appreciate criticism and other ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is neither crazy nor terrible.

You've started some type hinting (good!) but it's incomplete. For instance

```
self._issues: Set[str] = set()
```

and

```
@property
def checkers(self) -> Tuple[
    Callable[
        [], 
        Tuple[bool, str],
    ], ...
]:
```

Note that it's good practice to add hints accepting the most generic possible type and return the most specific possible type, so `Tuple` instead of `Iterable`.

There's not a whole lot of win in having `_issues` as a private with a public accessor, because private is only a suggestion in Python and users can still get to that member. You might as well just have a public `issues` set. However, the better thing to do is make this class stateless - keep your `checkers` (which can be made public - again, private is kind of a lost cause in Python); do not store `issues` on the class; and yield issues as a generator from `check()`.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please provide an implementation for `check` with generators? Not really sure how it will look like.

Comment: def check(self) -> Iterable[str]:
        for checker in self._checkers:
            ok, issue = checker()
            if not ok:
                yield issue

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I would really keep it simple. I would drop the OOP and just write a simple function that validates the radar and returns a list of issues. To be clear:

```
def check_radar(radar: Radar) -> Set[str]:
    return {
        *_check_1(radar),
        *_check_2(radar),
        ...
    }

def _check_1(radar: Radar) -> Set[str]:
    # perform check and return set() or {"issue"}
```

The example above is just an idea for the implementation, you can then implement the internals as you wish, for instance by defining a list of checker functions and iterating and appending to the list as you're doing in your sample code. The issues could be `str` or some more complicated object, depending on your needs.

This not only avoids having to write and maintain a class that in the end has just a single method kind of an unusual interface, but also writing a class that behaves like an `Iterable[str]` and which make the API harder to understand.

Another note: instead of `ok, issue =  checker()` you could just return `None` when there's no issue, which would simplify early returns from the checker functions.

I know it's not really OOP, but there's no need to use OOP everywhere if another pattern solves the problem more intuitively.